# Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Permission Set Groups

Tags: permission-set-groups

**Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Permission Set Groups**

Received some very strange error today. I am trying to build a new package and include three permission set and one permission set group to include those three permission set. I am trying to install this package to some old org. Does it mean some org do not have Permission Set Groups enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean some org do not have Permission Set Groups enabled?

Yes! This sometimes occurs with very old orgs: nominally global changes to enable new features might not actually take place on those orgs.

If you must use this old org, I'd suggest you open a case to get help with enabling the new feature.

Comment: Strange, really I expected continuous upgrades to enable all new features on every org!

Answer (score 0):

I have open a SF Support Case to shed some light on this.

1. There is [a known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003gwtQAA) which has deceiptful status: it should be "No Fix" instead of "Fixed" since it is still not working and not possible to enabled PSG. If this were fixed in Summer 20, now every org created before Summer 20 should have PSG enabled.
2. There is some conditional check in the internal Salesforce Code which provides an option to enable PSG for paid editions of Salesforce created before Summer 20 but not allowing to enable PSG for free editions.
3. There might be existing subscribers without PSG feature on paid editions which will prevent them from installing my package. To mitigate this, we might enable Delete metadata components pilot to delete PSG from the subsequent release of the package.